# How does OS cache fat-jar content?

Tags: javascript, java, jar, jvm, single-page-application

There is a way to deploying java applications within fat-jar. You compile and build all the files and put into single file, your backend with REST api and frontend - javascript files. As a server you use embedded one - jetty, tomcat, scalatra etc. How does (and where) operating system cache the content of jar file while running `java -jar`? (I'm interested mostly in ubuntu and centos) I ask in context of serving that javascript file to the client. [In worst imaginable case the system might extract the whole jar file each time the http request comes, that would be horrible]

Comment: Why not package as an installer? When jar is run first time extract all the contents and tell the user start application from extracted files?

Comment: Why ask from the perspective of the OS? Whatever happens, its the JVM doing the job.

Comment: I'm sure that jvm keeps only class definitions in memory (stack) and where does resources go? to other part of memory?

Comment: @Willmore I don't fully understand what do you mean, but the fat-jar way is status quo and we are not going to change it now

Comment: I read that `you compile and put backend with REST api and frontend - javascript files into one jar`. So why not extract this all content to a directory and let then the server serve those files from it. Each time you deploy a new version of your jar extract the files needed to serve (.js, etc.) once. The http server on request then would cache those files I assume.

Comment: this is not relevant here, all you you want from fat-jar is simplicity of calling `java -jar  fatjar.jar` no additional extractions.

Comment: did you already hit to the problem you anticipated: "In worst imaginable case the system might extract the whole jar file each time the http request comes, that would be horrible]"?

Comment: yes, but that was with vaadin when there was unique name generated for javascript file each time someone sent request